# ESXI 6.7 Dell Poweredege SNMP

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell, snmp, dell-perc

Is there a possibility to monitor a DELL R640 via SNMPGET?

Installed VMWARE ESXI 6.7 DELL Customized.

On my Debian Machine

```
snmpwalk -O fn -m ALL -c public -v 2c ipaddress .1.3.6.1.4.1.674
```

but I get

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.674 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

I want to monitor the Raid Status of the PERC H330 Mini.

Comment: Have you try to run `snmpwalk` w/o `OID` and use grep to find the RAID `OID`?

Comment: no result when i'm trying to grep for 674 ...

Comment: Grep RAID string

Comment: still no output - I think that the DELL OMSA vib didn't ship the OIDs for 674 ..

Comment: Maybe you can contact VMware about this...